# Validate a string is a binary number in PHP

Tags: php, string, binary, validation

In PHP the `bindec()`function can be used to convert a binary number to decimal, but there is no error checking to test if the binary number string is valid.  What happens is that something like `bindec('1051');` returns 5 instead of an error.

Is there an efficient way to validate if the number is a binary string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('~^[01]+$~', $num)) {
    // valid binary number
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do:

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-1]+$/", $var)) { 
   // do something 
}
```